# Undefined index errors in php

Tags: php, compiler-errors, syntax-error

i wrote below PHP codes in IntejiIdea,but when i run this codes in my localhost,this errors are show :

```html
 Notice: Undefined index: username in B:\dev\project\web\ted\login.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: password in B:\dev\project\web\ted\login.php on line 7
```

My php codes:

```html
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("ted_db",$con);


$user=$_POST['username'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];


$sqlQ="select * from users where Username='$user' ";
$result=mysql_Query($sqlQ);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);



if($row[2]==""){
    print "no user";
}
else if($pass!=$row[3])
{
    print "wrong password";
}else{
    print "ok";
}


mysql_close($con);

?>
```

i am confused,please help me my frineds.

Comment: how you get `$_POST['username']`.print out $_POST and check the vaues

Comment: i get $_POST['username'] in eclipse for android.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam i am creating a login form in android application,that connect to my database.

Comment: it seems your php script not getting data as post method

Answer (score 0):

first check if you are passing the values username and password keep a check if you do not wish to display errors 
try this

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("ted_db",$con);

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
$user=$_POST['username'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];


$sqlQ="select * from users where Username='$user' ";
$result=mysql_Query($sqlQ);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);



if($row[2]==""){
    print "no user";
}
else if($pass!=$row[3])
{
    print "wrong password";
}else{
    print "ok";
}


mysql_close($con);
}
else{
echo "No username or password passed..";
}
?>
```

This should be working without errors

**EDIT**

I believe you are sending GET request from JAVA not POST request, As i am not really much familiar in java there is a slight change in the code
check below

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("ted_db",$con);

if(isset($_REQUEST['username']) && isset($_REQUEST['password'])){
$user=$_REQUEST['username'];
$pass=$_REQUEST['password'];


$sqlQ="select * from users where Username='$user' ";
$result=mysql_Query($sqlQ);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);



if($row[2]==""){
    print "no user";
}
else if($pass!=$row[3])
{
    print "wrong password";
}else{
    print "ok";
}


mysql_close($con);
}
else{
echo "No username or password passed..";
}
?>
```

let me know how this goes

Comment: i copy and past you code,run th code and see this line:No username or password passed..   what happen??username and password do not passed.where is the problem???i am confused.please help me

Comment: Yes that means you are not passing the username correctly paste the complete code how are you send your username and password

Comment: i pass username and password in loginServer Class in eclipse

Comment: i am write the LoginServe class above the post.plase check this class.tnx Dear nani

Comment: edited the previous answer check back and let me know, instead of $_POST i have given $_REQUEST as the values you are sending may be GET or POST , $_REQUEST accepts both $_POST and $_GET

Answer (score 0):

```html
package com.acharapp.ted;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class loginServer extends AsyncTask {

    private String Link = "";
    private String User = "";
    private String Pass = "";


    public loginServer(String link, String user, String pass) {

        Link = link;
        User = user;
        Pass = pass;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

        try {

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(User, "UTF8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Pass, "UTF8");

            URL mylink = new URL(Link);
            URLConnection connect = mylink.openConnection();

            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line);

            }

            TEDActivity.res = sb.toString();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return "";
    }

}
```